# Monadwidget in Frontend type

Tags: reflex, reflex-dom

Some of the examples use monadwidget, with mainwidget. While obelisk generated project expects you to use a frontend data type. I couldn't find a reference to this type in the guide, but how would you use monadwidget within the type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're supposed to use prerener or prerender_:

```hs
prerender_ blank $ bodyElement
```

Youll have to disable cors too: [Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)

Source: https://github.com/obsidiansystems/obelisk/issues/320